# How to create cylinder pie using `ParametricRegion`?

Tags: graphics3d, finite-element-method, regions, opencascade

I'm  wondering that this simple definition of a cylinder pie doesn't work

```
pie = ParametricRegion[ {r Cos[\[CurlyPhi]], r Sin[\[CurlyPhi]],z}, {{r, 5 , 10 }, { \[CurlyPhi], -\[Phi]/2, \[Phi]/2}, {z, 0 ,2 }}]
```

Evaluating `Region` needs around 28 seconds to complete (very slow )

```
Region[pie]
```

[image]

`DiscretizeRegion` fails after some time

```
DiscretizeRegion[pie] (*DiscretizeRegion::drf: DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region ParametricRegion[<<2>>].*)
```

`MeshRegion[pie]` only shows the input.

What's wrong here? Is there a fast workaround? Thanks!

My goal is to combine several pies later (*Union`)

Comment: `Region[pie]` shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhACJ.png). I am on v12.2.0 Win7-x64.

Comment: `pie = With[{\[Phi] = \[Pi]/2}, 
  ParametricRegion[{r Cos[\[CurlyPhi]], r Sin[\[CurlyPhi]], 
    z}, {{r, 5, 10}, {\[CurlyPhi], -\[Phi]/2, \[Phi]/2}, {z, 0, 2}}]];
pie // Region`

Comment: (assuming `\[Phi]` has a value assigned before `pie` is defined) is `Region@RegionConvert[pie, "Implicit"]` any faster?

Comment: @kglr Thanks! I started with `ImplicitRegion[]` with polar parameters `r,\[CurlyPhi],z` but wasn't able to plot it, because RegionPlot3D expects cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible workaround:

```
apie = RegionProduct[Annulus[{0, 0}, {5, 10}, {0 Degree, 30 Degree}], 
   Line[{{0}, {2}}]];
bpie = RegionProduct[
   Annulus[{0, 0}, {7, 12}, {15 Degree, 45 Degree}], 
   Line[{{0}, {1}}]];

Region[#, Boxed -> True] & /@ {apie, bpie, RegionUnion[apie, bpie]}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Unfortunately `MeshRegion[RegionUnion[apie, bpie]]` still doesn't evaluate. Any idea why?

Comment: `MeshRegion[DiscretizeRegion[...]` would work. You can also use *mcells* within `DiscretizeRegion` command. I tried: `MeshRegion[
 DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[apie, bpie], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.1}, AccuracyGoal -> 2]]` Anything more aggressive results in a memory allocation failure as I have 8GB only.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an accurate workaround:

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
face = OpenCascadeShape[
   Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]];
sweep = OpenCascadeShapeRotationalSweep[face, {{2, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0}}, 
   N[30 Degree]];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[sweep];
Show[BoundaryMeshRegion[bmesh], bmesh["Wireframe"]]
```

[image]

To get a full element mesh:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ToElementMesh[bmesh, "MaxCellMeasure" -> Infinity]
```

This returns a mesh with 139 elements. If you want a first order mesh use:

```
ToElementMesh[bmesh, "MaxCellMeasure" -> Infinity,"MeshOrder"->1]
```

Compare this with:

```
apie = RegionProduct[Annulus[{0, 0}, {5, 10}, {0 Degree, 30 Degree}], 
   Line[{{0}, {2}}]];
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[apie]
```

[image]

Look at the accuracy of the corners.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer. Didn't know this package. Is there also a command to mesh the complete volume?

Comment: So, OpenCascadeLink ships with Mathematica. Search for it in the help system. What it returns in a boundary ElementMesh. This then can be meshed with `ToElementMesh`.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, [OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html), or check out the OpenCascade tag on this site.

Comment: Thank you, `ToElementMesh[bmesh]` works fine. But if I try  `ToElementMesh[bmesh[[1]]]`   to create a simple rough mesh , the result is wrong at the concave side of the volume. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: The result is not wrong, if you ask `ToElementMesh` to create a list from coordinates it computes a convex hull. To get a mesh use `ToElementMesh[bmesh]`, perhaps with some max cell measure, or by specifying options to `OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh`

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, I'll try it. My hope was to find an easy way to get the minimal number of 3d-elements (as bmesh did for surface elements)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, see update.